# AVPlayer playing wrong video file

Tags: ios, swift, caching, avfoundation, avplayer

I am having a weird situation and have no clue how to handle this , I am downloading the videos from firestorage and caching into device for future use , meanwhile the background thread is already doing its job , I am passing a video url to the function to play the video. The issue is that sometimes avplayer is playing the right video and sometimes taking some other video url from the cache.

you can find the code in below :

```
  func cacheVideo(for exercise: Exercise) {
    print(exercise.imageFileName)
    guard let filePath = filePathURL(for: exercise.imageFileName) else { return }
    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath.path) {
        //  print("already exists")
    } else {
        exercise.loadRealURL {  (url) in
            print(url)
            self.getFileWith(with: url, saveTo: filePath)
        }
    }
}
```

writing file here

```
    func getFileWith(with url: URL, saveTo saveFilePathURL: URL) {
    
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        
        print(saveFilePathURL.path)
        if let videoData = NSData(contentsOf: url) {
            videoData.write(to: saveFilePathURL, atomically: true)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // print("downloaded")
            }
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let error = NSError(domain: "SomeErrorDomain", code: -2001 /* some error code */, userInfo: ["description": "Can't download video"])
                print(error.debugDescription)
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now playing the video using this

```
func startPlayingVideoOnDemand(url : URL) {
    
    activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
    activityIndicatorView.isHidden = false
    print(url)
    let cachingPlayerItem = CachingPlayerItem(url: url)
    
    cachingPlayerItem.delegate = self
    cachingPlayerItem.download()
    // cachingPlayerItem.preferredPeakBitRate = 0
    let avasset = AVAsset(url: url)
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avasset)
    let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    player.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false
    initializeVideoLayer(for: player)
    
}
```

any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: U can double check for the url that the function is called with : 
func startPlayingVideoOnDemand(url : URL) in both the cases and the difference might be probably different urls in the two scenarios.

Comment: I already fixed thanks

Answer (score 0):

this was solved because the data model which i was using to download bunch of videos files was accessed in background thread and meanwhile i was trying to assign the url to the same data model class in order to fetch the video and play in avplayer. Hence this was the issue and resolved by simply adding a new attribute into data model for assigning the url to play right away.